# How calc Rank with this data in my database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have table that store questions each question have different answers and each answer have different weight and now i want to Calculation the rank but i don't now how do this.please help me
i use sql server
i have this table stored answers and weight of each answer

```
AdminQuesAns
=======================
Id     QuesId    Ans       Value
10     1000      Yes        10
11     1000      somewhat   5
12     1000      No         0

10     1001      Yes        0
12     1001      No         10
```

and this table store Customer answers

```
AdminRank
==================================
Id     SDId    QuesId    AnsValue  
1      100      1000      10
2      100      1001      0
```

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result? (Well formatted text, please.)

Comment: What rdms are you using? (mysql,oracel,mssql)

Comment: How do you going to calculate rank(equation)?

Comment: @jarlh a number as rank(between 0 and 100)

Comment: i need query like  :select (sum(AdminRank.Ansvalue)*100)/(select distinct sum(max(AdminQuesAns.Value))

Comment: If you know which query you need, then what is your question? And again: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The question has been tagged under sql, so hopefully it's SQL Server.

Comment: @RohitKumar: The tag `sql` is for generic SQL questions. "SQL" is used by all relational databases.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Absolutely agreed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I'd go about it.

This has an inner query which gets the max value for each question, then the outer query pairs those with the values from the individual answers, sums across the questions and calculates one as a percentage of the other.

I'm also grouping by SDId, on the assumption that that is the ID of the person filling out the survey.

```
SELECT 
    ar.SDId,
    100 * cast(sum(ar.AnsValue) as numeric(5,2)) / sum(mv.maxValue) as Rank
FROM
    AdminRank ar
JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        qa.QuesId,
        max(qa.Value) as maxValue
    FROM
        AdminQuesAns qa
    GROUP BY
        qa.QuesId
    ) mv on ar.QuesId = mv.QuesId
GROUP BY
    ar.SDId
```

Depending on your data types you may be able to remove the `cast` part.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query.

**1.**

```
Select  SDId ,b.QuesId,
((sum(a.AnsValue) *100)/(Select sum(c.value)
from AdminQuesAns c where c.QuesId =b.QuesId))as'Rank'
from AdminRank a join AdminQuesAns b on a.QuesId=b.QuesId and value=AnsValue
group by  SDId ,b.QuesId
```

Comment: @user2983227 Please check if this works for you, you can change partition_by_clause and order_by_clause accordingly.

Comment: i need query like :select (sum(AdminRank.Ansvalue)*100)/(select distinct sum(max(AdminQuesAns.Value))

Comment: @user2983227 As you have marked it under SQL Server, the above answer should serve your purpose.

Comment: This is not exactly that i wanted but very good.tanQ.with this query i must programmatically calculate sum of rank column and then divide it to number of rows

Comment: @user2983227 Pleased to know it was useful for you.